# i'm getting a (expected unqualified-id before "." token, in my arduino IDE just for typing ".global". here's the assembly code

Tags: assembly, avr

```
#define __SFR_OFFSET 0x00
#include "avr/io.h"

.global START
.global BTN_LED

START:
SBI DDRB, 2
SBI DDRB, 3
SBI DDRB, 4
CBI DDRD, 2
CBI DDRD, 3
CBI DDRD, 4
RET

BTN_LED:
SBIC PIND, 2
RJMP RED_LED_ON
SBIC PIND, 3
RJMP GREEN_LED_ON
SBIC PIND, 4;
RJMP BLUE_LED_ON
RJMP BTN_LED


RED_LED_ON:
LDI R21, 10 //CONTROLL FLASH TIMES
RED_AGAIN:
SBI PORTB, 2
RCALL XDELAY
CBI PORTB ,2
RCALL XDELAY
SUBI R21,1
BRNE RED_AGAIN
RJMP BTN_LED

GREEN_LED_ON:
LDI R21, 10 //CONTROLL FLASH TIMES
GREEN_AGAIN:
SBI PORTB, 3
RCALL XDELAY
CBI PORTB ,3
RCALL XDELAY
SUBI R21,1
BRNE GREEN_AGAIN
RJMP BTN_LED

BLUE_LED_ON:
LDI R21, 10 //CONTROLL FLASH TIMES
BLUE_AGAIN:
SBI PORTB, 4
RCALL XDELAY
CBI PORTB ,4
RCALL XDELAY
SUBI R21,1
BRNE BLUE_AGAIN
RJMP BTN_LED

.EQU DELAYVAL, 1000
XDELAY:
LDI R20, 90
OUTER:
LDI R30, lo8(DELAYVAL)
LDI R31, hi8(DELAYVAL)
INNER:
SBIW R30,1
BRNE INNER
SUBI R20, 1
BRNE OUTER
```

Comment: That sounds like a C compiler error. Make sure you are assembling it with the assembler and not compiling as C. If you rely on autodetection you should follow the appropriate naming convention. Could be caused by naming your file `foo.asm` instead of `foo.s` for example. Also consult the settings in your IDE if applicable.

Comment: Does it assemble (but not link) without the `.global` directives?  Or do you then get more errors like you'd expect if you fed some asm to a C compiler?

Comment: @PeterCordes
it gives me more errors

Comment: @Jester
i'll try the naming method

Comment: Ok, then your question title about `.global` is misleading; it's not that directive that's the problem.  Almost certainly Jester is correct; that looks right to me given the error message about tokens, and "unqualified-id" is something that comes up in C terminology.